# How to add new RAID-1 as second datastore on ESXi 5.5

Tags: esxi

long time no see, but there is a topic I need your help with.

I'll try to be precise and short.

Hardware: 
INTEL 1HE Server System (R1304SPOSHBN)
(CPU and RAM are useless here i guess) 
Avago 4-Port 9341-4i SAS3/SATA Controller 12Gb/s
Already configured RAID-1 in Slot 1 and 2 with 2TB 
Running VMware ESXi 5.5

I have two new HDDs with 8TB each. Now I need to add them as a second RAID-1 in slot 3 and 4 of the server and want them to be a second datastore in ESXi.

Well, I'm new to this topic and a bit scared I could misconfigure something in the BIOS RAID, so that the first RAID will be lost or data corrupted or something like this.

RAID-1 in Slot 1 and 2 came preconfigured as we bought the server.

I hope this information is enough, let me know if it is not.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. 
There is a possibility to add a virtual RAID Controller to ESXi (which did not work in my case).

See:
https://www.broadcom.com/products/storage/raid-controllers/megaraid-sas-9261-8i#downloads

And:
https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/MegaRAID_Controller_in_VMware_%C3%BCberwachen

Otherwise, the solution is to add a new virtual disc group in the RAID-BIOS, then boot and let ESXi search for new datastores.